# MySQL SELECT rows as successive columns

Tags: mysql, null, mysql-workbench

I have this table named 'Values' in a MySQL database:

```
sp_id   W   Value_C Top_C
742     11  11.42   1.15
742     12  114.35  2.44
742     13  27.2    0.42
742     14  55.38   6.2
742     15  23.77   16.7
15      11  10.59   9.15
15      12  12.4    12.3
15      13  157.89  0.72
15      14  51.2    1.5
15      15  11.78   0.51
117     11  27.48   0.92
117     12  21.416  0.76
117     13  75.31   0.39
117     14  2.182   0.79
252     11  15.54   0.25
252     12  10.209  0.32
252     13  14.41   0.44
252     14  68.34   2.16
```

I am looking to rearrange the data. I am looking to get this:

```
sp_id  11       11      12      12      13      13      14      14      15      15
742    11.42    1.15    114.35  2.44    27.2    0.42    55.38   6.2     23.77   6.77
15     10.59    9.15    12.4    12.3    157.89  0.72    51.2    1.5     11.78   0.51
117    27.48    0.92    21.416  0.76    75.31   0.39    2.182   0.79    NULL  NULL
252    15.54    0.25    10.209  0.32    14.41   0.44    68.34   2.16    NULL  NULL
```

I can get them as columns, but I am having difficulty getting them as rows. When I use `CASE`, I am getting `NULL`s in many places.

How could I `SELECT` this subset with a `MySQL` query?

EDIT: Corrected the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this if the `W` values are limited :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ff0c/3)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ValuesTable
    (`sp_id` int, `W` int, `Value_C` decimal(10,2), `Top_C` decimal(10,2))
;

INSERT INTO ValuesTable
    (`sp_id`, `W`, `Value_C`, `Top_C`)
VALUES
    (742, 11, 11.42, 1.15),
    (742, 12, 114.35, 2.44),
    (742, 13, 27.2, 0.42),
    (742, 14, 55.38, 6.2),
    (742, 15, 23.77, 16.7),
    (15, 11, 10.59, 9.15),
    (15, 12, 12.4, 12.3),
    (15, 13, 157.89, 0.72),
    (15, 14, 51.2, 1.5),
    (15, 15, 11.78, 0.51),
    (117, 11, 27.48, 0.92),
    (117, 12, 21.416, 0.76),
    (117, 13, 75.31, 0.39),
    (117, 14, 2.182, 0.79),
    (252, 11, 15.54, 0.25),
    (252, 12, 10.209, 0.32),
    (252, 13, 14.41, 0.44),
    (252, 14, 68.34, 2.16)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VT.sp_id, 
       VT11.Value_C as 11v, VT11.Top_C as 11t,
       VT12.Value_C as 12v, VT12.Top_C as 12t,
       VT13.Value_C as 13v, VT13.Top_C as 13t,
       VT14.Value_C as 14v, VT14.Top_C as 14t,
       VT15.Value_C as 15v, VT15.Top_C as 15t
FROM ValuesTable VT
LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT11 ON VT.sp_id = VT11.sp_id AND VT11.W = 11
LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT12 ON VT.sp_id = VT12.sp_id AND VT12.W = 12
LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT13 ON VT.sp_id = VT13.sp_id AND VT13.W = 13
LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT14 ON VT.sp_id = VT14.sp_id AND VT14.W = 14
LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT15 ON VT.sp_id = VT15.sp_id AND VT15.W = 15
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ff0c/3/0)**:

```
| SP_ID |   11V |  11T |    12V |  12T |    13V |  13T |   14V |  14T |    15V |    15T |
|-------|-------|------|--------|------|--------|------|-------|------|--------|--------|
|   742 | 11.42 | 1.15 | 114.35 | 2.44 |   27.2 | 0.42 | 55.38 |  6.2 |  23.77 |   16.7 |
|    15 | 10.59 | 9.15 |   12.4 | 12.3 | 157.89 | 0.72 |  51.2 |  1.5 |  11.78 |   0.51 |
|   117 | 27.48 | 0.92 |  21.42 | 0.76 |  75.31 | 0.39 |  2.18 | 0.79 | (null) | (null) |
|   252 | 15.54 | 0.25 |  10.21 | 0.32 |  14.41 | 0.44 | 68.34 | 2.16 | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Hi, yes, there are a limited number of W values. However, from your reply, I am having trouble understanding the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s: `LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable **VT11** ON VT.sp_id = **VT11.sp_id** AND **VT11.W = 11**`. Could you please explain a.) what is `VT11` and b.) how multiple `OUTER JOIN`s work in this case?

Comment: VTxx are aliases for the table. There is one JOIN per W value. Doing this allow you to display values from different rows on the same one but in differents columns...

Comment: Your solution works and I understand now about the table alias. But, I am still confused about the `AND` in the `OUTER JOIN` statements. Do you mean this: `LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT11 ON VT.sp_id = VT11.sp_id AND LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT11 ON VT.sp_id = VT11.W = 11`

Comment: `VT.sp_id = VT11.sp_id AND VT11.W = 11` ...This will look for entries that have the same `sp_id` as the one extracted from `ValuesTable VT` and also that have 11 as value for `W` There is no `AND` directly before `LEFT OUTER JOIN`...

Comment: ^^^ Thank you for that comment. That explains it. I mis-understood where the `AND` was located. One last question: You created the table `ValuesTables`. In my case, if ValuesTable is a derived table, then I cannot assign an alias like you do here: `ValuesTable VT11 `. In my case, I am having to replace this code by a copy of the derived table. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: You can have `FROM (SELECT * FROM whatever) VT11` ( see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdb67/1 ) You can also create a temporary table

Comment: ^^^ Here is what I meant: A.) `SELECT DISTINCT VT.sp_id, VT11.Value_C as 11v, VT11.Top_C as 11t FROM (SELECT * FROM test) AS ValuesTable LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT11 ON VT.sp_id = VT11.sp_id AND VT11.W = 11`. Now, B. `SELECT DISTINCT VT.sp_id, VT11.Value_C as 11v, VT11.Top_C as 11t FROM (SELECT * FROM test) AS ValuesTable LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM test) AS VT11 ON ValuesTable.sp_id = VT11.sp_id AND VT11.W = 11`. Only B. works. A is how you have done it. Unfortunately, it seems like A does not work for me so I have to use the full derived table twice (B.). Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You are correct that only B will works. But You can create a temporary table and use it after...`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ValuesTable (...); INSERT INTO ValuesTable SELECT * FROM test; SELECT DISTINCT VT.sp_id, VT11.Value_C as 11v, VT11.Top_C as 11t FROM  ValuesTable LEFT OUTER JOIN ValuesTable VT11 ON VT.sp_id = VT11.sp_id AND VT11.W = 11` See here http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3844811/Make-Your-MySQL-Queries-More-Efficient-with-Temporary-Tables.htm

Comment: Thank you. All my questions here have now been answered.